# Emphatic pronoun question

Tags: punctuation

I'm curious as to why an emphatic pronoun isn't set off by commas. For example, "I, myself, completed the puzzle."

Thanks!

Comment: The parenthetical use your have there emphasizes itself as a countering or contradicting clause, unlike an emphatic pronoun which emphasizes the subject noun. I am sure they can help you more over on English SE!

Comment: The use of punctuation is primarily a matter of *style*, so the best place to start is with the style guide of the institution or company you intend to publish your writing with. PS what do you mean by "emphatic pronoun"? Did you mean "reflexive pronoun"? Adding some parenthetical commas is perfectly ok.

Comment: @WeckarE. this question would generally not receive an answer on EL&U - there's half a dozen questions about comma usage every week, and the answer in every case (posted as a comment, prior to voting to close) is "it's a matter of style". They are then quickly closed as "primarily opinion-based".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. And sorry I posted it in the wrong place! : ) I'll head over there.

Answer (score 0):

Commas are tricky. However what I've learned is to use them where you would pause reading it.

That sentence seems to stop in weird places with the *I, myself,*.

But I'd reject here on grounds of pure readability, it gets in the way of understanding. You could wait for an award from the grammar police, or get your message across.

I would say that you could think of *myself* could a reflexive pronouns. I take my understanding of this from French. *I myself comb my hair* for example.
If the sentence were, *I, Ramses, Son of Horus, consort of Ti, and Lord of upper and lower Egypt do proclaim it to be so*, I'd agree with you.

It seems that whatever is between the commas should be able to stand as the subject on its own. *Myself completed the puzzle* would not work.